# Quadratics Solutions problem

Tags: quadratics

For what values of $m$ does $x^2−4x−m=0$ have no real solutions while $x^2−9x+m^2=0$ has at least one real solution?

Comment: Recall the discriminant of quadratic equation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Have a look at the discriminant $D=b^2-4ac$ for $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$

If $D<0$ the equation $f(x)=0$ has no real solution. If $D\geq 0$  the equation $f(x)=0$ has at least one real solution.

Answer (score 0):

take the first equation 
$$f(x)=x^2-4x-m$$
$$f'(x)=2x-4=0\rightarrow x=2$$
for real solution the  $f(2)\geqslant 0$

and for no real solution if $f(2)<0$

For the second equation

for real solution the  $f(4.5)\geqslant 0$

and for no real solution if $f(4.5)<0$

Comment: not clear OP knows calculus

Comment: @gt6989b However, this is another way to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

The first equation has no real solution provided $$(-4)^2-4(-m)=4(4+m)\lt 0,$$ while the second has at least one real solution provided $$(-9)^2-4m^2=3^2-(2m)^2\ge 0.$$

Both conditions are satisfied when both inequalities hold *simultaneously.* Can you continue now?

Comment: I would strongly prefer for the OP to do some work on the problem instead of us solving everything for him.

Comment: @gt6989b I don't think your definition of *everything* agrees with the most accepted one, which I had assumed.

Comment: indeed, which is why i removed the -1 after some thought, but left the comment... let's hope the op ends up doing something after your hint...